# Creating a 64 bit version of a 32 bit database

Tags: progress-4gl, openedge

I am using Linux and running 102b06. I have to create a 64 bit version of a 32 bit database. What is the best approach here? Its hard to find documentation for this task. I have tried dumping and loading but it appears you cannot dump all the tables with one command. My database has thousands of tables!

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The Progress database doensn't have a "bitsize" - that's strictly a program thing, so you can connect to and work with the database using either 32 or 64 bit binaries.

Answer (score 0):

Your db is a 10.2 db so it already has 64 bit rowids. Why do you think that it is "32 bit"?